# How to translate/localize background notifications in a flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

My notifications are not being localized when I receive them in the Android emulator.

I've created this file `android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string name="hello_world">Hello World!</string>
</resources>
```

I'm using a node project with [node-gcm@1.0.5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-gcm) to send the notification to firebase:

```js
import gcm from 'node-gcm';

const sender = new gcm.Sender('secret');
const message = new gcm.Message({ contentAvailable: true, priority: 'high', data: {} });
message.addNotification({
  title: 'Test title',
  body: 'Test body',
  title_loc_key: 'hello_world',
  body_loc_key: 'hello_world',
  icon: 'ic_launcher',
  click_action: 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
});

sender.send(message, { registrationTokens: userFcmTokens }, callback);
```

By rights, since hello_world is in the strings.xml, the notification should be `Hello World!`. However, I'm always receiving `Test title & Test body`... What am I doing wrong?

My `pubspec.yaml`

```yaml
firebase_core: ^1.20.0
firebase_messaging: ^12.0.1
```

Comment: Have you found any solution to this issue?

Comment: @AustrianDude unfortunately no. I have created an issue but it's still open: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/3938